# Array size assigning Error in C programming?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, sum

In mention code the error is Run Time because of array size assigning to new variable

C language

```
{ scanf("%d",&n);//size of array
int arr[n];
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
 scanf("%d",&givensum);
int i=0;
int j=n-1; // RUN TIME ERROR ? WHY for j=n is No ERROR
 while(i<h)
 {

     if((arr[i]+arr[j]) == givensum){
        printf("%d %d %d\n",arr[i],arr[j],givensum);
        c++;
     }
     if((arr[i]+arr[j]) > givensum)
     {
       j--;
        c++;
     }
      if((arr[i]+arr[j]) < givensum)
      {
          i++;
          c++;
      }
      if(c == 0)
      printf("-1");
 }
cases--;
}
return 0;
```

}

The Above line 6
n above Code the n is for size of array(Let take n=7 ) and assigning the size of array to some other variable like int j; j=n;// Its working fine But the size of array the j=7 and actual size of array become 8(i.e 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7) on counting the number from 0 to 7 it is 8 ans actual size is 7 Only if I assign the value j=n-1; then the Runtime Error occur ? Help Me

https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/SuA0hcfL14

Comment: What type is `j`? What is the *exact* error you get? This code is incomplete, many definitions are missing.

Comment: Run Time Error while i am practicing on geeksforGeeks Portal i.e segmentation fault because of array size "n" assignment to variable "int j"

Comment: Please indent your code consistently.

Comment: I have provided the link for Code please help through it

Comment: You should provide the complete code here in question, too - tried the one in your link, ran into a loop with undefined behaviour (`c` variable being incremented until signed integer overflow). You should provide the concrete input leading to crash (or even better: replace `scanf` calls with assignment of concrete values). By the way: you don't ever check the result of these calls. `scanf` function family returns number of successfully scanned variables.

Answer (score 1):

'C' does **not** provide any array boundary checking. If you write arr[7] for array of size 7, you corrupt memory. There will be no run-time error. It can cause a crash, changing values in other unrelated variables, but no intended run-time error.

So, you yourself need to make sure that you do not write (or read for the same matter) outside of the array boundaries. Not sure why you are talking about `j`, it is not used anywhere else in your code fragment. I see only `i` and `h`, where the latter is not even declared.

You have to make sure that neither `i` nor `h` get bigger than `n-1` (or less than 0).

BTW, `j = n-1` is just a simple assignment and is not related to the size of the array.

Comment: Sorry for code , j and i only use through out the code and i want to do read the array size n  and and assign n size to some other variable called j so any changes to j value not reflect the change in original size n Because i later preceed with program there is change in the value of size of array so I don't want to change the size of array therefore i am assigning the array size to variable called j and that vaiable is using through out the code with out effecting the original variable n

Answer (score -4):

You cannot dynamically assign array size in C. Please take an array that has required size by properly initializing the size.

Consider for example, I am going to use at max 10 numbers any time during the program then I should initialize the array as follows:

```
int a[10];
```

Comment: did you consider [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)?

Comment: So How can we do that please help

Comment: Most C implementation don't support VLA

Comment: @Varun If VLA aren't supported, then you already get a compilation error - which obviously was not the case here, so VLA *are* supported by compiler in use.